# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [X] and [Y] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/url] which is not permitted

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets, mapping, illegalargumentexception

I tried to add this servlet

```
package com.classmgt.servlet;

@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {}
```

to my Eclipse project, by editing the `web.xml` as below

```
<servlet>
    <description>Servlet to print out Hello World!</description>
    <display-name>ControllerServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.classmgt.servlet.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ControllerServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

However, I got the following exception:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ClassManagementSystem]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/ClassManagementSystem]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [ControllerServlet] and [com.classmgt.servlet.ControllerServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/ControllerServlet] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2457)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2100)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1300)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:369)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5269)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried adding `metadata-complete="true"` to `web.xml`, but it does not recognize the servlet anymore.

Comment: Looks like there is two servlets and the same url-pattern but according to your web.xml there is only one, maybe wront web.xml is running? Try recompiling and restart?

Comment: Did you mix annotation-based and web.xml-based configuration?

Comment: inside my ControllerServlet I put this:
`@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")`
and at my form this is what I put:
`<form action="ControllerServlet" method="POST">`

Answer (score 38):

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named
>   [ControllerServlet] and [com.classmgt.servlet.ControllerServlet] are
>   both mapped to the url-pattern [/ControllerServlet] which is not
>   permitted

It seems that you have mixed `@WebServlet` annotation based and `web.xml` based configuration.

I doubt that you created a Servlet using the "Create Servlet" wizard which creates web.xml entry with url-pattern and then , added a `@WebServlet` annotation which duplicates anything you may put in the web.xml.

You should use the one or the other, not both. Remove the mapping from `web.xml` and go ahead with using only the `@WebServlet` annotation.

Read more: [Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations) and [our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Answer (score 11):

Just remove the annotation `@WebServlet("/ControllerServlet")`, from the `ControllerServlet`, because it already added in the `web.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named...
```

I fetched this cause where I create new servlet in different package (name='syncro'). My servlet located in ***syncro.SynchronizeServlet***
And when I add information about this servlet in deployment descriptor (web.xml) I catch error: ***IllegalArgumentException***

Example of incorrect descriptor part:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>SynchronizeServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SynchronizeServlet</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/SynServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

When I add correct path for servlet - error  disappeared. Correct desc below:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>syncro.SynchronizeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SynchronizeServlet</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/SynServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

==> 73!

Comment: Hello! 
73 - In amateur radio means "with best wishes, success, good luck"

Comment: Thanks. Thats an advanced type of leetspeak.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is doing a 'clean'.

My issue was caused when the Servlet class was renamed. However, the original .class files remained in the target directory (with their Servlet annotation).  It looks like you moved your ControllerServlet into a package.

Jetty didn't seem to mind these apparent duplicates, but Tomcat7 gave your
'both mapped to the url-pattern' exception.

The easy way to see if this is causing your issue is to look in the WAR to see if both the old classes (in your case [ControllerServlet] and [com.classmgt.servlet.ControllerServlet]) are both there.

Answer (score 0):

As for me I added the tom-cat version to my pom file and it worked

```
<properties>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.52</tomcat.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The servlets named [Register] and [com.TeamWork.controller.Register]
>   are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Register] which is not permitted

getting this error you have to remove your servlet mapping from web.xml and just add @WebServlet("/Register") annotation + url

```
<servlet>
     <servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>com.TeamWork.controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

then your servlet class on the top add this one

```
@WebServlet("/Register")`
public class Register extends HttpServlet { }
```

it will work thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was an unexpected error in Intellij Idea.

I deleted a servlet 2 days back which was having the same URL pattern. However, I am getting the error that my new servlet and that deleted one have the same URL pattern. This was strange.

1. Tried cleaning the Tomcat v10.0.23 server,
2. Restarted the server,
3. Build the exploded artifact,
4. Restarted IDE.

Nothing works!!

Finally, I run the project in debug mode and that fix my issue.
This is strange but maybe I did something wrong that's why I faced this issue.

Hope this can help someone if they're facing the same issue.