# Tomcat 7.0.42 not starting in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets, tomcat7

I am having a problem with my web.xml file.
I created a eclipse dynamic web project with Web module version: 3.0
By default there was no web.xml file se I created one by myself.

Now when I try to run the project I am getting this error:

```
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\PharosSystems\Core;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;.
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AJAX_J2EE' did not find a matching property.
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 792 ms
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AJAX_J2EE]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AJAX_J2EE]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [testController] and [servlet.testController] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/testController] which is not permitted
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)
at       org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2450)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2132)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2093)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsFile(ContextConfig.java:2086)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1293)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:878)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:376)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5322)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more

Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:800)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more

Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:691)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]    
Aug 31, 2013 3:53:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I have had the same issue earlier with other project on my office machine which I was able to deal with by cleaning the server in eclipse.

Right now I have cleaned my servers and deleted servers but same result. If I remove the servlet module from web.xml project runs. Thats why I guessed problem is with servlet mapping but I cant see the fault.

My Web.xml:

```
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>AJAX_J2EE</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/pages/index.html</welcome-file>    
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <display-name>testController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>testController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.testController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/testController</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: From the logs:  

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [testController]                                    and [servlet.testController] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/testController] which is not permitted
at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:335)  

I can imagine you didn't post your complete web.xml. can you have a look?

Comment: @blackbird014 .. that is my complete web.xml. I omitted the root node that I just updated.
I have mapped only one servlet in xml file and only one servlet src/servlet/testController.java

Comment: and you have a package call servlet including a class testController then looks correct... try just to call the package not servlet and the testController.java, TestController.java starting uppercase like should be by convention. I have no other ideas.

Comment: thanks blackbird014. I found my mistake from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16277469/2596762). Posted the answer too. Thanks for taking the effort and time to help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16277469/2596762).

I had created Servlet using "Create Servlet" wizard which adds a @WebServlet(/servletName) annotation and no entry in web.xml

I then created a entry in web.xml manually which duplicated the entry at the runtime.

So you have to do either of the two with Servlet 3.0.

1. Use Annotation like:

   ```
   @WebServlet("/testController")
   public class testController extends HttpServlet {    }
   ```

   OR
2. create a web.xml entry for your servlet.

Read more: [Servlet 3.0 Annotations](https://blogs.oracle.com/swchan/entry/servlet_3_0_annotations)

Comment: If you for some reason want to keep both the configurations in web.xml and the annotation, write in the annotation:
@WebServlet(name="YourServletName",urlPatterns={"/YourURL"})
Where YourServletName and YourURL are the ones given in web.xml

Answer (score 3):

Here in pom.xml you have missed writing (`<scope>provided</scope>`) in the dependency of servlet So in dependency of servlet you just have to add (`<scope>provided</scope>`) in pom.xml
e.g. `<dependency>`
    `<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>`
    
`<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>`
    
`<version>2.0</version>`

`<scope>provided</scope>`

`</dependency>`

 "or"
`<dependency>`
    
`<groupId>servletapi</groupId>`
    `<artifactId>servletapi</artifactId>`
    
`<version>2.4</version>`
`<scope>provided</scope>`

`</dependency>`
This solution worked for me .

Thank you