# java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, eclipse-neon

When I am trying to run my project it shows this type of error.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Temp]]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Temp]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
  ... 6 more 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [MyServlet] and [temp.MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:327)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:320)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2389)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2066)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1952)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1153)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5077)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  ... 6 more

Dec 12, 2016 12:53:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal SEVERE: A child container failed during start java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source) 
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495) Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)  
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Dec 12, 2016 12:53:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start  
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:948)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655) 
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
```

1. IDE: Ecilpse-neon
2. server:Tomcat v9.0
3. Java: 1.8.0 ( in Tomcat also)
4. Added jar:

   - catalina-4.1.31
   - catalina-ant-6.0.37
   - catalina-ha-6.0.13
   - catalina-tribes
   - javax.servlet-3.0
   - servlet-api-2.5-6.1h.6

MyServlet.java

```
//@WebServlet("/MyServlet")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public MyServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("Hello..............");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Temp</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>temp.MyServlet</servlet-class>

  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/MyServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

}

How Can I solve those error?

Comment: `The servlets named [MyServlet] and [temp.MyServlet] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/MyServlet] which is not permitted` -- Does that mean anything to you?

Comment: As the error suggests you have 2 servlets with same URL mapping. Post code for MyServlet and temp.Myservlet

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, I am using `@WebServlet` Annotation and ***same url pattern mapping for two different servlet***, after changing the url pattern in one of the servlet, Tomcat successfully started for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [X] and [Y] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/url] which is not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270619/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-servlets-named-x-and-y-are-both-mapp) this and it works!!!!!!!!

> It seems that you have mixed @WebServlet annotation based and web.xml
>   based configuration.
>
> I doubt that you created a Servlet using the "Create Servlet" wizard
>   which creates web.xml entry with url-pattern and then , added a
>   @WebServlet annotation which duplicates anything you may put in the
>   web.xml.
>
> You should use the one or the other, not both. Remove the mapping from
>   web.xml and go ahead with using only the @WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Delete the server.

Step 2) Click on window and then select preferences.

Step 3) Select server & then select Runtime Environments.

Step 4) Select & remove the runtime environment. Example : Apache Tomcat v9.0

Step 5) Again select & add runtime environment. Example : Apache Tomcat v9.0

Step 6) Select Tomcat Installation directory : which is parent directory of bin folder.

Step 7) Click finish and then click apply & close button to add runtime environment successfully.

Step 8) Click on window & then show view and select server.

Step 9) Click the link to create a new server, select the server and click finish.

Step 10) Right click and start the server.

Step 11) If any problem then change the ports, right click & open.

Step 12) Change the Tomcat admin port to 8080 or any four digit number, & similarly change port for HTTP/1.1 to 8000 or any four digit number.

Step 13) Save the port changes.

Step 14) Run the server, the problem is solved.

Answer (score -2):

It has worked after when I have removed @WebServlet annotation from my Myservlet.java.But I can't understand why it didn't work with @WebServlet

Comment: This is not the correct solution. Check the comments and post your code.