# Apache TomCat not starting

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, servlets

So, I'm pretty much just starting with *servlets*, *jsp* and *apache tomcat* inside *eclipse*.

I'm doing a project, which was already working, and I accidentally opened a HTML form (which send data to a java method with post) with the web editor inside of *eclipse* (which does not support the slovenian letters `ščćžđ`, and the encoding got messed up.

Upon opening back in the default editor and fixing the messed encoding, the file could not be saved. It gave me a popup about ISO encoding and how it needs to be as UTF8 so I just clicked yes and then *apache* would load not just the forms and methods, it wouldn't even open the whole website (index, etc..)..

When I tried some other fix I found on the web, it gave me `404`, `500`, and a bunch of other errora..Heck now it won't even run (I located the problem inside the web.xml file --when its commented out, the server runs but off course nothing runs..)..

Here is the error message:

```
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Naloga1spletnaTRGbootstrap' did not find a matching property.
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Mar 27 2017 14:25:04 UTC
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.13.0
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_121-b13
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\Eclipse2_delovno_okolje\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\apache-tomcat-8.5.13
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\Eclipse2_delovno_okolje\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\apache-tomcat-8.5.13
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\Eclipse2_delovno_okolje\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\apache-tomcat-8.5.13\endorsed
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Denis Bobovnik\Desktop\FERI\1. letnik\2. Semester\OST - Osnove Spletnih Tehnologij\eclipse;;.
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:21 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 987 ms
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.13
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Naloga1spletnaTRGbootstrap]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Naloga1spletnaTRGbootstrap]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The servlets named [SejnoUgibanje] and [si.um.feri.ost.bobovnik.seje.SejnoUgibanje] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/SejnoUgibanje] which is not permitted
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMappingDecoded(WebXml.java:323)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.web.WebXml.addServletMapping(WebXml.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationWebServlet(ContextConfig.java:2389)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2066)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1952)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsWebResource(ContextConfig.java:1946)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1153)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:775)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:655)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
apr. 09, 2017 5:19:22 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetKalkulator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>si.um.feri.ost.bobovnik.zahteve/GetKalkulator</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetKalkulator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetKalkulator</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>GetZahteva</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>si.um.feri.ost.bobovnik.zahteve/GetZahteva</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>GetZahteva</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/GetZahteva</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>PostKalkulator</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>si.um.feri.ost.bobovnik.zahteve/PostKalkulator</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>PostKalkulator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/PostKalkulator</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SejnoUgibanje</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>si.um.feri.ost.bobovnik.seje/SejnoUgibanje</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SejnoUgibanje</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SejnoUgibanje</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Try clean and build.  Also take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270619/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-the-servlets-named-x-and-y-are-both-mapp)

Comment: Do all of your "servlet-class" entries really have a forward slash in them?  It needs to be a dot (a.k.a. period, full stop) character.